Flutter: Namespace not specified. Specify a namespace in the module's build file
This is showing after trying AGP Upgrade Assistant in Android Studio.

I am not missing the namespace in neither build.gradle:
plugins {
//    id "com.android.application"
//    id "kotlin-android"
//    // The Flutter Gradle Plugin must be applied after the Android and Kotlin Gradle plugins.
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
    // Uncomment if using Firebase Performance Monitoring
    // id 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '2.0.0' apply false
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('../../apps-keys/my_rents/key.properties')
println("Keystore properties file exists: ${keystorePropertiesFile.exists()}")
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
    println("Keystore properties loaded: ${keystoreProperties}")
} else {
    throw new GradleException("Keystore properties file not found: $keystorePropertiesFile")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.drodriguez.my_rents"
    compileSdk = flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion = flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId = "com.drodriguez.my_rents"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdk = 23
        targetSdk = flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode = flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName = flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias = keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword = keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile = keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword = keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
        debug {
            keyAlias = keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword = keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile = keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword = keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source = "../.."
}

dependencies {
//    https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup?hl=es
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.6.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.6.1'
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:7.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[8,9)'
    implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:6.17.0.0'
    // Firebase performance
//    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:21.0.1'
//    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core' // deprecated
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:22.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:23.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:25.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:19.0.3'
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.9.0'
}

or AndroidManifest:
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.drodriguez.my_rents">

I tried to get rid of the package throwing the error: https://pub.dev/packages/contacts_service
and used a more updated and recommended one: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_contacts
This also allowed me to update other packages... but I get now the same error with a different package.

Well, those dependencies are not compatible with your AGP version it seems. Make them fix their builds, or get maintained alternatives. If you cannot, there are dirty work-arounds that you should easily find if you search for your problem as you are by far not the first one hit by this. ;-)

Unfortunately that was the fix; install new dependencies and update my code. I can't updating package by package
